# Excel cannot find dates (regardless of formatting options)

Tags: vba, date, excel

My boss keeps a small excel file that mimics the desk calendar we use to keep track of random things at our job, like hours and counts of reports sent. It's laid out in a grid of 7x5 (roughly 5, the last row only has a few cells in it since the months aren't generally divisible by 7).

How the dates and such work is the first cell, A1, has the first date of the month. Each subsequent cell was hand-coded by my boss to take the value of the date cell in the tile before it and add 1. However, these cells aren't side-by-side, they are splayed out. I am trying to get it to sum each weeks total hours (and reports), but when I attempt to call the `Cells.Find` method, it doesn't return anything.

I thought that perhaps it was because the cells are formatted in the American fashion of `mm/dd/yy`, so I tried to search for `05/12/14` and it didn't work. So I attempted to search for the default date format that the `Date()` function returns, `m/d/yyyy`, and it still doesn't find anything. I've tried to set the `.Find()` to check both Values and Formulas, and neither works. Even if I use the `ctrl+F` to find them by hand, it tells me there is no such value in the work sheet.

I've searched around, and none of the posts that I found had a solution that worked - the `Cells.Find` method always returns either `A1`, the first time it is called, or `Nothing` on every subsequent call.

My code currently is minimal, but here it is.

### Code

```
 Sub Worksheet()
    Dim r As Range, d As Date, fwkn As Integer, lwkn As Integer, wkn As Integer, col As Collection
    'The purpose of this is to get the week totals using the below functions.
    
    d = DateValue([A1].Value)
    fwkn = WeekNum(d) 'First week number
    d = DateSerial(Year(d), month(d) + 1, 1) - 1 'Gets us the last day of the month
    lwkn = WeekNum(d) 'Last Week Number
    last_of_month = Day(d)
    For i = 1 To last_of_month
    
        d = DateSerial(Year(d), month(d), i)
        Set r = Cells.Find(What:=d, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=Range("a1"))
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print r.Address
        End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
Function WeekNum(d As Date) As Integer
' You can see examples of this at
' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/weeknum.htm
   WeekNum = CInt(Format(d, "ww", vbMonday))
End Function
```

Does anyone have any idea why Excel wouldn't find the date?

Comment: did you look at what's really in the cells, and the formatting rules being applied?

Comment: yes I did. The cells, other than the A1 cell, are all `A1+1`, `E1+1`, ... , `Y1+1`, `A14+1`, ... and all are formatted `mm/dd/yy`

Comment: As stated, I tried both xlValues and xlFormulas, in both the VBA window and the regular "Find" window from the program itself.

Comment: you are searching for a date - excel stores the date internally as a number. to get the number that represents a date (and to be able to find it on a spreadsheet) use `CLng`

Comment: @SeanCheshire, tried it, doesn't find any results that way (as of now it finds the value in A1, but nowhere else)

Comment: Dates are tricky, dependent on formatting and Windows Regional Settings.  You can loop through UsedRange, or some defined range, checking CLng(d) against the .Value2 property; or you can search for strings that match the format of the date in the cells (e.g: what:=format(d,"m/d/yy") or however they are formatted.  For the latter, you should lookin:=xlvalues

Comment: @RonRosenfeld : I tried that, still does not work. Starting to think this is impossible.

Comment: @Jhecht Not sure what you tried.  I've posted an example of using looping to find dates -- and the dates are entered in a variety of formats.  If it works for you, you should be able to adapt it to your needs.  If not, I'd have to look at the actual data.

Comment: @Jhecht I just edited my answer to correct a typo which caused the routine to omit the last day of the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of using looping to find the dates. The dates are in a variety of formats, including text:

[image: Sample Dates on Sheet]

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindDatesLooping()
    'Some date in A1
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim D As Date
    Dim I As Long

Set R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
D = CDate([A1])

For I = 1 To Day(DateSerial(Year(D), Month(D) + 1, 0))
    D = DateSerial(Year(D), Month(D), I)
        For Each C In R
            If D = C Then
                Debug.Print C.Address, D
            End If
        Next C
Next I
End Sub
```

Returns in the Immediate Window:

```
$C$3          5/3/2014 
$E$5          5/15/2014 
$D$7          5/20/2014 
$A$1          5/28/2014
$G$8          5/31/2014
```

Dates in the immediate window are in US format m/d/yyyy; but if I change my Regional Settings, the immediate window dates will return in whatever format (and all five dates are still returned).

Comment: Thank you.  Entering "15-5-14" results in text and is not found.  Is this because of my Regional Settings?  (I'm in Wyoming).

Comment: @dcromley Yes.  The only date above that is text is the one marked as such.  The others were entered as real dates and different formatting applied.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
Set r = Cells.Find(what:=DateValue(d), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=Range("a1"))
```

From: Chip Pearson http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm#Finding

EDIT: OK, it should have LookIn:=xlValues, sorry

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
  Cells(1, 1) = "5/1/2014"
  Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(31, 1)).Formula = "=a1+1"
  Dim i&, fwkn&, lwkn&, wkn&, last_of_month&
  Dim r As Range, d As Date
  'The purpose of this is to get the week totals using the below functions.
  d = DateValue([A1].Value)
  fwkn = WeekNum(d) 'First week number
  d = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) + 1, 1) - 1 'Gets us the last day of the month
  lwkn = WeekNum(d) 'Last Week Number
  last_of_month = Day(d)
  For i = 1 To last_of_month
    d = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), i)
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=DateValue(d), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=Range("a1"))
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print r.Address
    End If
    Cells(i, 2) = r.Address
  Next i
End Sub

Function WeekNum(d As Date) As Integer
  ' You can see examples of this at
  ' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/weeknum.htm
  WeekNum = CInt(Format(d, "ww", vbMonday))
End Function
```

Comment: Tried it, still only outputs $A$1;

Comment: I've tried it on two different computers. Does not find anything. In Debug mode it doesn't even get to the Debug.Print statement.

Comment: Maybe add this 2nd line.  I don't know why I didn't need that.   `Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(31, 1)).Formula = "=a1+1"` 
`Columns(1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"`

Comment: Need @Jhecht on previous comment.

Comment: why would I change the number format on the A column? The dates are not listed solely in that column. I think I just need to find a work around because even in the program's find window it still doesn't find a date, no matter how I search for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54655/discussion-between-dcromley-and-jhecht).

Answer (score 1):

The range has to be the full area you want to search, not just the initial cell.

```
set c = Cells.Find(CDate("1/1/2015"), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
```

This line should set c to the cell you are looking for. Notice there is no range, as I'm simply using `Cells` to refer to the entire sheet.
You need to save this address (if it's not `Nothing`) as vba will keep looping if not checked to stop.

```
firstAddress = c.Address
```

now you can keep looking if there are more dates to find:

```
Do 
    'do your stuff here, then look for the next cell
    Set c = .FindNext(c) 
Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
```

Comment: Cells isn't set to be inside a range, it's just the Cells property of the sheet the macro is on. Either way your answer does not work, it does not find the date "5/2/2014" (that was the only thing about your code I changed)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not sure but I think it is LookIn:=xlFormulas that helped me